# How to say ".... in both A and B" in french

Tags: traduction

I know I can use "tous les deux" or "les deux" to mean "both", but in most of the examples I found, they are followed by a single noun in plural form (like "les deux théories"), so how do I translate "both" in "... in both A and B"

Comment: Can you specify a little bit more of the context? Depending on that context, the answer may vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use *à la fois*:

> ***À la fois** en A **et** en B.*

Following your comment :

> *X est un espace de Hausdorff **à la fois** dans la topologie des boîtes **et** dans la topologie produit.*
> *X est un espace de Hausdorff dans la topologie des boîtes **ainsi que** dans la topologie produit.*
> *X est un espace de Hausdorff dans la topologie des boîtes **comme** dans la topologie produit.*
> *X est un espace de Hausdorff **aussi bien** dans la topologie des boîtes **que** dans la topologie produit.*
> *X est un espace de Hausdorff **autant** dans la topologie des boîtes **que** dans la topologie produit.*

Note: in the previous sentences, ***en*** might be better than ***dans la*** but this is a different question.

Comment: so I can say something like "X est Hausdorff à la fois dans la topologie des boîtes et la topologie produit"?

Comment: In that case, I would probably use *autant* although I'm not sure to understand what X might be.

Comment: @Dylech30th You have to repeat "dans" : "*X est Hausdorff à la fois dans la topologie des boîtes et **dans** la topologie produit*" (if this is Math, we'd say "*... à la fois **en** topologie des boîtes et **en** topologie produit*")

Comment: @Dylech30th Je préfère **dans** dans ce cas. "**dans** la topologie... et **dans** la topologie" me semble plus naturel dans ce contexte  mathématique. On pourrait vérifier dans Bourbaki.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sry for my late reply! That clarifies a lot and thanks for the examples you provided! (X should be a set)